# How can I add secondary submenus to my navigation?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, submenu

I have working drop-down menus in my page navigation, but now I want to add a second level of submenus and I don't know how to alter my code to make that happen. Simply adding another submenu within the first doesn't work because clicking on the open submenu item toggles the first menu closed instead of opening the second. I thought of creating a subsubmenu class and nesting that menu's toggling within the submenu's toggling code, but I'm a JavaScript novice and don't know where to begin to do that. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```js
// JavaScript Document

/*eslint-env es6*/

const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

/* Toggle mobile menu */
function toggleMenu() {
  if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
    menu.classList.remove("active");

    // adds the menu (hamburger) icon
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>";
  } else {
    menu.classList.add("active");

    // adds the close (x) icon
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";
  }
}

/* Event Listener */
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);



const menuitems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

/* Activate Submenu */
function toggleItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("submenu-active")) {
    this.classList.remove("submenu-active");
  } else if (menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
  } else {
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
  }
}

/* Event Listeners */
for (let item of menuitems) {
  if (item.querySelector(".submenu")) {
    item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
    item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
  }
}

/* Close Submenu From Anywhere */
function closeSubmenu(e) {
  if (menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    let isClickInside = menu
      .querySelector(".submenu-active")
      .contains(e.target);

    if (!isClickInside && menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
      menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    }
  }
}

/* Event listener */
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

.navcontainer {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menucontainer {
  background-color: #fff;
}

nav {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 9;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navimage {
  background-image: url('../images/nav-bkgd.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  height: 120px;
}

nav.scrolled {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}

nav a {
  color: #707070;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

nav .active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.menu,
.submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu a {
  line-height: 20px;
}

#navlogo {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px !important;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.item.button {
  padding: 4px 5px 0;
}

.item:not(.button) a:hover,
.item a:hover::after {
  color: #f47c23;
}

.current,
.current a {
  color: #f47c23;
}

.menu li.button a {
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Mobile menu */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.menu li.subitem a,
.submenu li.subsubitem a {
  padding: 10px;
}

.toggle {
  order: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.item.button {
  order: 2;
}

.item {
  order: 3;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.active .item {
  display: block;
}

.button.secondary {
  /* divider between buttons and menu links */
  border-bottom: 1px #444 solid;
}


/* Submenu up from mobile screens */

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-active .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.has-submenu i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.has-submenu>a::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f0d7";
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.subitem a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.submenu-active {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Tablet menu */

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .menu {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo {
    flex: 1;
  }
  #navlogo {
    height: 60px;
    max-height: 60px !important;
  }
  .navimage {
    height: 140px;
  }
  .item.button {
    width: auto;
    order: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    order: 2;
  }
  /* Button up from tablet screen */
  .menu li.button a {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 80px;
  }
  .button a {
    background: #f47c23;
    border: 1px #f47c23 solid;
  }
  .button.secondary {
    border: 0;
  }
  .button.secondary a {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #f47c23 solid;
  }
  .button a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
    background: #f47c23;
    border-color: white;
  }
}


/* Desktop menu */

@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  nav {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .menu {
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    background: none;
  }
  .logo {
    order: 0;
  }
  .navimage {
    height: 170px;
  }
  .item {
    order: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
  .button {
    order: 2;
  }
  .buttonfloat {
    float: right;
  }
  .headerfloat {
    float: left;
  }
  .menu li.button a {
    margin: 9px 0;
  }
  .submenu-active .submenu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 60px;
    background: #ededed;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 180px;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .submenu-active {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .menu li a {
    padding: 10px 3px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navimage">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="index.html" id="logonav">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" id="navlogo" /></a>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><a href="index.html" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
      <li class="item has-submenu">
        <a tabindex="0" id="categoriesnav">Categories</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="subitem"><a href="category1.html" id="category1nav">Category1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I want to add another submenu below Category1 to list Category1a and Category1b.